# Get all child nodes from XmlNode by node

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

I have an XML like the following:

```
<config>
 <EPackets>
  <packet>
   <id> 1 </id>
   <name> packet1 </name>
   <variables>
    <variable>
     <id> 1 </id>
     <name> packet1var1 </id>
    </variable>
    <variable>
     <id> 2 </id>
     <name> packet1var2 </id>
    </variable>
   </variables>
  </packet>
  <packet>
   <id> 2 </id>
   <name> packet2 </name>
   <variables>
    <variable>
     <id> 1 </id>
     <name> packet2var1 </id>
    </variable>
    <variable>
     <id> 2 </id>
     <name> packet2var2 </id>
    </variable>
   </variables>
  </packet>
 </EPackets>
</config>
```

For the sake of brevity, let's assume that I only want to print said nodes by console in the following manner:

```
Config contains:
packet: packet1
id: 1
variables of the packet:
-- name: packet1var1
-- id: 1
-- name: packet1var2
-- id: 2
packet: packet2
id: 2
variables of the packet:
-- name: packet2var1
-- id: 1
-- name: packet2var2
-- id: 2
```

At the moment I can get the outer info, but when I try to access the inner element variables for each packet, nothing is returned (inner foreach):

```
List<XmlNode> PacketList = variablesSettings.getNodes("config.EPackets.packet");

log("Config contains: ", DEBUG);

foreach (XmlNode packet in PacketList)
{
    int packetId = Convert.ToInt32(packet.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText);
    String packetName = packet.SelectSingleNode("nombre").InnerText;

    log("packet: " + packetName, DEBUG);
    log("id: " + packetId, DEBUG);
    log("variables of the packet: ", DEBUG);

    foreach (XmlNode variable in packet.SelectNodes("variables.variable"))
    {
        String variableName = variable.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
        String variableId = variable.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;

        log("name: " + variableName, DEBUG);
        log("id: " + variableId, DEBUG);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? any info would be appreciated.

The problem, to summarize, is that when I try to get the inner nodes (variables) from each packet using this line `foreach (XmlNode variable in packet.SelectNodes("variables.variable")` the program ends (It finds 0 nodes with that name)

Comment: String variableName = packet.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
String variableId = packet.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;  --- should use from variable instead of packet?

Comment: @Mohan you're correct, but it was a typo, I have it with vriable in my code.

Comment: You use wrong XPath in [`SelectNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes#System_Xml_XmlNode_SelectNodes_System_String_). You should use `/` (not `.`) as descendant selector. The correct XPath is `packet.SelectNodes("variables/variable")`. I'm not sure, however, about `variablesSettings.getNodes(…)`, because we don't know what is the type of `variablesSettings`.

Comment: @PeterWolf I see what you mean. I found a workaround in which I can select the las child of the packet and then iterate there (it gives the desired reult)